# Make issues with oxfRPiCameraVideoGrabber on the Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm currently working though the CreepyPortrait tutorial from Adafruit, but I'm having trouble getting the project to Make on my RaspberryPi

The terminal output is below:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/openFrameworks/apps/myApps $ git clone http://github.com/tdicola/creepyportrait
Cloning into 'creepyportrait'...
remote: Counting objects: 149, done.
remote: Total 149 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (149/149), 35.97 MiB | 1.16 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (43/43), done.
pi@raspberrypi ~/openFrameworks/apps/myApps $ cd creepyportrait/
pi@raspberrypi ~/openFrameworks/apps/myApps/creepyportrait $ make
armv6l
checking pkg-config libraries:   cairo zlib gstreamer-app-1.0 gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0 gstreamer-base-1.0 libudev freetype2 fontconfig sndfile openal openssl libpulse-simple alsa gtk+-2.0 libmpg123 
Compiling OF library for Release
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/openFrameworks/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project'
armv6l
checking pkg-config libraries:   cairo zlib gstreamer-app-1.0 gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0 gstreamer-base-1.0 libudev freetype2 fontconfig sndfile openal openssl libpulse-simple alsa gtk+-2.0 libmpg123 
armv6l
checking pkg-config libraries:   cairo zlib gstreamer-app-1.0 gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0 gstreamer-base-1.0 libudev freetype2 fontconfig sndfile openal openssl libpulse-simple alsa gtk+-2.0 libmpg123 
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'ReleaseABI'.
armv6l
checking pkg-config libraries:   cairo zlib gstreamer-app-1.0 gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0 gstreamer-base-1.0 libudev freetype2 fontconfig sndfile openal openssl libpulse-simple alsa gtk+-2.0 libmpg123 
Done!
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/openFrameworks/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project'


Compiling creepyportrait for Release
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/openFrameworks/apps/myApps/creepyportrait'
armv6l
checking pkg-config libraries:   cairo zlib gstreamer-app-1.0 gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0 gstreamer-base-1.0 libudev freetype2 fontconfig sndfile openal openssl libpulse-simple alsa gtk+-2.0 libmpg123 
Compiling addons/ofxRPiCameraVideoGrabber/src/ofxRPiCameraVideoGrabber.cpp
g++-4.7 -c -O3 -Wall -march=armv6 -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard -fPIC -ftree-vectorize -Wno-psabi -pipe -DOF_USING_GTK -DOF_USING_MPG123 -DTARGET_RASPBERRY_PI -DSTANDALONE -DPIC -D_REENTRANT -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -DTARGET_POSIX -DHAVE_LIBOPENMAX=2 -DOMX -DOMX_SKIP64BIT -DUSE_EXTERNAL_OMX -DHAVE_LIBBCM_HOST -DUSE_EXTERNAL_LIBBCM_HOST -DUSE_VCHIQ_ARM -DUSE_DISPMANX_TRANSFORM_T -std=c++11 -DLOAD_SKULL -I./addons -I./addons/ofxRPiCameraVideoGrabber -I./addons/ofxRPiCameraVideoGrabber/src -I./src -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/src -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2 -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/legacy -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/video -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/features2d -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/imgproc -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/calib3d -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/ml -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/core -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/highgui -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/gpu -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/contrib -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/flann -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/ts -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/objdetect -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/lib -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/lib/linuxarmv6l -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2 -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/legacy -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/video -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/features2d -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/imgproc -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/calib3d -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/ml -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/core -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/highgui -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/gpu -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/contrib -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/flann -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/ts -I../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/objdetect -I../../../addons/ofxRPiCameraVideoGrabber/src -I/opt/vc/include -I/opt/vc/include/IL -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host/linux -pthread -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/include/alsa -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I../../../libs/fmodex/include -I../../../libs/glfw/include -I../../../libs/glfw/include/GLFW -I../../../libs/kiss/include -I../../../libs/openssl/include -I../../../libs/openssl/include/openssl -I../../../libs/poco/include -I../../../libs/rtAudio/include -I../../../libs/tess2/include -I../../../libs/openFrameworks -I../../../libs/openFrameworks/video -I../../../libs/openFrameworks/sound -I../../../libs/openFrameworks/gl -I../../../libs/openFrameworks/types -I../../../libs/openFrameworks/utils -I../../../libs/openFrameworks/graphics -I../../../libs/openFrameworks/math -I../../../libs/openFrameworks/events -I../../../libs/openFrameworks/communication -I../../../libs/openFrameworks/3d -I../../../libs/openFrameworks/app  -MMD -MP -MF obj/linuxarmv6l/Release/addons/ofxRPiCameraVideoGrabber/src/ofxRPiCameraVideoGrabber.d -MT obj/linuxarmv6l/Release/addons/ofxRPiCameraVideoGrabber/src/ofxRPiCameraVideoGrabber.o -o obj/linuxarmv6l/Release/addons/ofxRPiCameraVideoGrabber/src/ofxRPiCameraVideoGrabber.o -c addons/ofxRPiCameraVideoGrabber/src/ofxRPiCameraVideoGrabber.cpp
make[1]: g++-4.7: Command not found
../../../libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project/makefileCommon/compile.project.mk:191: recipe for target 'obj/linuxarmv6l/Release/addons/ofxRPiCameraVideoGrabber/src/ofxRPiCameraVideoGrabber.o' failed
make[1]: *** [obj/linuxarmv6l/Release/addons/ofxRPiCameraVideoGrabber/src/ofxRPiCameraVideoGrabber.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/openFrameworks/apps/myApps/creepyportrait'
../../../libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project/makefileCommon/compile.project.mk:126: recipe for target 'Release' failed
make: *** [Release]
```

Error 2

Answer (score 0):

From [config.make](https://github.com/tdicola/creepyportrait/blob/master/config.make):

```
ifeq ($(PROJECT_ARCH),armv6l)
# Explicitly use GCC 4.7 on Raspberry Pi. This is necessary on Raspbian
# because the installed GCC version doesn't support C++11.
PROJECT_CXX = g++-4.7
PROJECT_CC = gcc-4.7
endif
```

Your error:

```
make[1]: g++-4.7: Command not found
```

indicates that you have (probably) g++ 4.6, but not g++ 4.7.

According to [GCC 4.7.1 in Raspbian](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=11390):

> by plugwash » Mon Jul 16, 2012 3:29 pm: We do have 4.7.1 in raspbian
>   (package gcc-4.7), it just isn't the default. The same is true of all
>   ports of debian wheezy EXCEPT i386 and amd64.

you should be able to install that package (not tested by me).